Non-empty closed subsets of compact space has choice function？
My question is as follows.
(question) Let X be any compact space, and C(X) consists of all non-empty closed subsets. Then, does C(X) have choice function ？　Of course, you can't use any form of axiom of choice.
I am ashamed to say that I have no idea.

I’m not sure what the question is. By Axiom of Choice, every collection of nonempty sets admits a choice function.

Without any form of Axiom of Choice, the answer is no. The cofinite topology on any (nonempty) set $X$ defines a compact topology. Then non-empty closed subsets are exactly nonempty finite subsets of $X$ and $X$ itself. So if a choice function always exists in such cases, Axiom of Finite Choice, which is independent from ZF, follows.

The cofinite topology on an infinite set is quasi-compact but not Hausdorff. So this argument only shows that the AC for closed subsets of a quasi-compact space inplies the axiom of finite choice.

@user14111 To me, compactness never entails Hausdorff. But that’s a difference between different areas of math, I suppose.

To show equivalence with the full AC, for any disjoint collection $X_i$ of nonempty sets, we can form the topology whose closed sets are exactly the finite unions of the $X_i.$ This topology is compact (for much the same reason as the cofinite topology is) and obviously a choice function on the nonempty closed sets gives a choice function for the $X_i.$

Yes, of course. In my answer I assumed the sets $X_i$ were finite in order to stay on the safe side in case the OP's definition of compact space included Hausdorff. I bet the axiom of choice for closed subsets of a compact Hausdorff space is weaker than the full AC.

@user14111 Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to get across in your first and second sentences of this comment, but your answer fails when the $X_i$ are infinite because in that case they are not closed, not because the space isn't Hausdorff.

@user14111 To your third sentence, yes the ultrafilter lemma suffices. If $X$ is compact Hausdorff, its closed sets are compact Hausdorff subspaces, and the ultrafilter lemma proves that a product of nonempty compact Hausdorff spaces is nonempty (and compact Hausdorff).

I assumed the sets $X_i$ were finite because otherwise I would have to use your non-Hausdorff topology.

In fact ZF does not even imply choice for disjoint nonempty closed subsets of a compact metric space, since that would imply the aciom of choice for countable families of nonempty finite sets.

The statement you want to prove is not a theorem of ZF, because it implies that any family $(X_i:i\in I)$ of pairwise disjoint nonempty finite sets has a choice function. To see this, consider the set $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$ as a topological space with the discrete topology, and note that the sets $X_i$ are closed sets in the one-point compactification of $X$.
P.S. We have shown that the AC for closed subsets of a compact Hausdorff space implies the axiom of choice for finite sets. The other answers merely show that the AC for closed subsets of a quasi-compact space implies the axiom of choice for finite sets. The question could be read either way, but I consider it likely that the OP meant "compact" in the sense that includes Hausdorff.
